# ERROR 2017 in simple pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here's my entire script. It's supposed to look in a Project Gutenberg etext and strip out the header and footer text, just leaving the actual text of the book, so it can then be used in further analysis.

```
ebook = LOAD '$ebook' USING PigStorage AS (line:chararray);
ranked = RANK ebook;

header = FILTER ranked BY SUBSTRING(line,0,41)=='*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK';
hlines = FOREACH header GENERATE $0;
headers = RANK hlines;
--STORE headers INTO '/user/PHIBBS/headers' USING PigStorage;

footer = FILTER ranked BY SUBSTRING(line,0,39)=='*** END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK';
flines = FOREACH footer GENERATE $0;
footers = RANK flines;
--STORE footers INTO '/user/PHIBBS/footers' USING PigStorage;

blocks =  JOIN headers BY $0, footers BY $0;
sectioned = CROSS blocks, ranked;
--STORE sectioned INTO '/user/PHIBBS/sectioned';

book = FILTER sectioned BY $4 > $1 AND $4 < $3;
STORE book INTO '/user/PHIBBS/clean/$ebook';
```

It fails with "`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.`"

If I try just running a subset of the script, it's fine up until the very last line. If try running the first 5 lines plus the commented-out `STORE` line, it's fine. If I run the next 3 lines plus the next commented-out `STORE` line, it falls over. If I disable EITHER of the STORE lines, it works just fine. So each individual `STORE` statement, no problem. Both of them? `ERROR 2017`! Any suggestions? I've tried on two different distributions, one from Hortonworks and one from Cloudera, clean VM images freshly downloaded from their respecitve websites.

Answer (score 0):

Given your objective of striping out the headers/footers and just having the book, you don't really need to store anything but the book and the headers/footers.  I think your problem is `blocks =  JOIN headers BY $0, footers BY $0;` which is doing a self join on data only loaded once.  I downloaded War & Peace and this code worked for me.

```
$ pig -x local
# grunt>

ebook = LOAD 'pg2600.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);
ranked = RANK ebook;

header = FILTER ranked BY SUBSTRING(line, 0, 41) == 'START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK';
hlines = FOREACH header GENERATE $0;
headers = RANK hlines;
STORE headers INTO 'headers' USING PigStorage();

footer = filter ranked by SUBSTRING(line, 0, 39) == 'END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK';
flines = FOREACH footer GENERATE $0;
footers = RANK flines;
STORE footers INTO 'footers' USING PigStorage();

/* Now re-load headers and footers for join */

h_new = LOAD 'headers/part-m-00000' USING PigStorage() AS (id:int, col1:int);
f_new = LOAD 'footers/part-m-00000' USING PigStorage() AS (id:int, col1:int);

blocks = JOIN h_new BY id, f_new BY id;
sectioned = CROSS blocks, ranked;
book = FILTER sectioned BY $4 > $1 AND $4 < $3;
STORE book INTO '__book__';
```

Comment: I was only storing the intermediate data as a test that it was working. Without them being written out at all, the final write fails anyway. Even just trying to write the two out, without doing anything after that (all commented out), the second write fails. Either write individually, with the other one commented out, works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just as well if you read your original input to two different variables.

```
ebook_header = LOAD 'pg2600.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);
ebook_footer = LOAD 'pg2600.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);
```

And apply corresponding filters to these. I suppose it depends on case whether it is better to read it in once, create two outputs and read in again or read in twice.

Comment: "It should work just as well"? I don't want it to work "just as well", because it doesn't work. I want it to work better, as in, to work! Is there a known problem with writing out more than one data set that are derived from the same source data set?

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusing answer. I meant to refer to this observation in the previous answer "_I think your problem is blocks =  JOIN headers BY $0, footers BY $0;_" and the suggested solution that you store your intermediate results. The other option is to read the original data into two different variables. I had a problem very similar to yours and both approaches seemed to solve the issue for me. Both on my ubuntu and aws. I think the problem is the join not writing, but the join is only really done when output is needed.